# C/C++ Check to see if bit 31 is set in an unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, bit

I'm trying to check and see if a bit is set in an unsigned int.  I'm not sure how I can do this, but I assume it would be something like this.  I'm trying to make the cdq instruction in C++ (but a function)

Here is what I have

```
unsigned int cdq(unsigned int eax)
{
     unsigned int edx = 0;

     if( (eax >> 31) & 1 ) { edx = 0xFFFFFFFF; }
     return edx
}
```

When I use the function with the following values:

cdq(0x12345678) bit 31 is set (1) so it should return (unsigned int)-1
cdq(0x01) bit 31 is not set (0) so it should return 0

The problem is it always returns 0, and I'm not sure why

Comment: How is bit 31 set in 0x12345678? The highest bit set is bit 28.

Comment: @juanchopanza "You need `eax>>30`" -- wrong.

Comment: `eax & 0x7FFFFFFF` is 0 if the "last" bit is 0, != 0 otherwise. Supposing unsigned int has at least 32 bits. Then note that in 0x12345678 bit 31 is not set.

Comment: @JimBalter I somehow read "31st bit" instead of "bit 31". My bad.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's pretty darn bad. It says bit 31 three times and the code tests for bit 31, so saying the OP needs `eax>>30` is bizarre, presumptuous, and a few other things ... especially considering that the function would *still* return 0 for 0x12345678. And the OP says they're trying to make the cdq instruction, which is plenty good explanation of why the function doesn't return bool. But the worst thing of all, even worse than your comment, is that someone clicked the uparrow on it.

Comment: @JimBalter You are right, it is truly terrible. I hope I live long enough to make amends for this unforgivable act. In the mean time, I have removed the offending comment, hoping that this act will go some way towards negating this aberration.

Comment: @juanchopanza With your rep I'm sure you've already made amends, and it was indeed an *aberration*. I trust that you aren't in the habit of such extreme errors.

Comment: Are you aware that an `unsigned int` need not be more than 16 bits in width? Are you aware that shifting greater than the width of the operand is undefined behaviour? Use a wider type, such as `unsigned long`, unless you *want* to rely upon coincidence rather than logic. Why is this question tagged both C++ and C? Please read [the C tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) before posting questions about C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> cdq(0x12345678) bit 31 is set (1)

No, it's not ... the highest bit set is bit 28:

```
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000
 ^  ^ 
 |  |
31  28
```

You code should work, but I would use

```
if( eax & (1U << 31) ) edx = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

since it's a bit more direct and it shifts a constant rather than a variable so does less work at run time (although an optimizing compiler should produce the same code for both).

Actually I would write something like

```
int cdq(int eax)
{
    return eax < 0? -1 : 0;
}
```

By the way, your code doesn't actually implement cdq because your eax and edx variables are not the hardware eax and edx registers. And it's really not a very good idea to replicate ASM instructions as C functions anyway ... C has its own features for doing these sorts of things, e.g.,

```
int32_t foo = -0x12345678;
int64_t bar = (int64_t)foo;
```

Comment: Good point @caf, but maybe you could just leave a comment since I was still in the process of refining this answer ... editing it is a bit aggressive.